# Restricting constructor in inherited class

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{

}
```

I have a case where I dont want anyone inheriting from the class should create any additional constructors other than the default constructor.

```
public class MyInheritedClass : MyClass
{

  MyInheritedClass(string name)
  {

  }
}
```

In the `myInheritedClass(string name)` should not be allowed. Is that possible?

Comment: Not, it is impossible.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, when some inherits, they are the one who owns the inherited class, and they can implement it in any way they want, unless someone stands nearby and hold their hands tightly.

Comment: Why on earth would you like to do this? It doesn't make any sense!

Comment: You can enforce your base class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent consumers/inheritors of your class implementing their own Constructor. However, you can enforce them to use your base class Constructor

That's to say, a class without an *Explicit Constructor* has a default *Parameterless Constructor*. Though, if you implement a Constructor with parameters and no *Paramterless Constructor*, your class won't be instantiable without arguments.

**Example**

```
public abstract class A 
{
    public A(string x) 
    {
    }
}

public class B : A 
{
    // If you don't add ": base(x)" 
    // your code won't compile, because A has a 
    // constructor with parameters
    public B(string x) : base(x)
    {
    }
}
```